# How to use float points in line chart

Tags: java, primefaces, jqplot

I'm trying to use a line chart with floating point values

This is an example of integer 1 and 2 for axes

```
series1.set(1,2);
```

How to insert 1,2 and 2,3

```
series1.set(1,2 , 2,3);
```

Comment: The decimal separator in JS is a dot, not a comma? Ie., write `1.2`, not `1,2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `series1.set(1.2 , 2.3);`use '.' instead of ','